# lucee.transformer.library.tag.TagLibException coldbox error

Tags: coldfusion, coldbox

I am trying to make a helper for my view. I want to edit the template css.

view filename: index.cfm
helper filename: indexHelper.cfm

my helper content:

```
<cfoutput>
  <style>
    .link-color{
      color:red;
    }
  </style>
</cfoutput>
```

Before i add the helper there is nothing wrong but after i added the helper i get this error.

Oopsy! Something went wrong!
Type: template
Messages: lucee.transformer.library.tag.TagLibException

Comment: What happens when you don't wrap style in output? I wonder if something thinks `<style>` is a ColdFusion tag.

Comment: @JamesAMohler actually the helper is not cause of the error. the error keeps showing sometimes.

Comment: "Sometimes" is a nebulous term. So how are you able to make this error happen?

Comment: @JamesAMohler there is no particular time when the error shows up. sorry i dont know how to make the error happen.

Comment: You need to come up with what is triggering this. You need to find the root error.

Comment: i will post the sreenshot if the error show up again.